# Fading individual characters with JQuery

Tags: jquery

A user can type a word in a popup with a prompt and then the letters of the string has to appear and disappear one by one.

But now only the last character of the string will appear and disappear.

```
var newHeadingText = prompt("Please provide a new heading:");          
for (var i = 0; i < newHeadingText.length; i++) {                    
    $("#main-heading").text(newHeadingText[i]).fadeOut(3000).fadeIn(3000);                
}
```

Thank you

Comment: `.text()` will set the text of the element to the value you specify. Without any sort of queue or timeout, the last iteration will be the only one you see, as you're essentially updating the text to each letter over the course of a few milliseconds.

Comment: for example you type: hallo. then it has to be: h .. a..l..l..o - so after three seconds the h then after three seconds a then after three seconds l..etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're currently resetting the value of `.text()` for each loop, which happens near-instantaneously.

Instead, I'd suggest making use of `setTimeout` to create a queue of sorts, where the first letter fades in immediately, the second letter fades in after a 6 second timeout, the third letter after a 12 second timeout, etc.

Other changes I've made:

- Added `.hide()` to start the heading as "hidden"
- Reversed `.fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` so that the last letter wouldn't fade out, then back in, then out again
- Set the timer to be `fadeTime * 2 * i` (We need to multiply it by 2 to compensate for both the fade in *and* fade out. We multiply it by `i` so the first one starts at 0, the second at 6000ms, the third at 1200ms, etc.)

---

Final product looks something like this:

```js
var fadeTime = 3000; //ms for fade-in, fade-out

var newHeadingText = prompt("Please provide a new heading:");
for (var i = 0; i < newHeadingText.length; i++) {
  fadeLetter(i);    //call our function with the current iteration
}

function fadeLetter(i) {
  setTimeout(      //Use setTimeout to queue fade animations
    function() {
      $("#main-heading").text(newHeadingText[i]).hide().fadeIn(fadeTime).fadeOut(fadeTime);
    }, fadeTime * 2 * i);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 id="main-heading">

</h1>
```